# eclipse cdt tools installing error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to install the CDT plugin on an exisitng 32-bit installation of Eclipse on Ubuntu Jaunty. I've tried both web-update and standalone-package install and both fail with the following error-

```
Application Started: 4000
!SESSION 2009-10-05 21:24:55.947 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20090611-1540
java.version=1.6.0_16
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -consolelog -debug

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse 4 0 2009-10-05 21:25:28.172
!MESSAGE Error while loading manipulator.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: !fwConfigLocation.equals(fwPersistentDataLocation)
    !fwConfigLocation=/opt/eclipse-galileo/configuration
    ,fwPersistentDataLocation=/opt/eclipse-galileo/plugins/configuration
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.checkConsistencyOfFwConfigLocAndFwPersistentDataLoc(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.loadWithoutFwPersistentData(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxManipulatorImpl.load(EquinoxManipulatorImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.loadDelegate(LazyManipulator.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.getConfigData(LazyManipulator.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction.uninstallBundle(UninstallBundleAction.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction.execute(UninstallBundleAction.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ParameterizedProvisioningAction.execute(ParameterizedProvisioningAction.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Phase.mainPerform(Phase.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningUtil.performProvisioningPlan(ProvisioningUtil.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProfileModificationOperation.doExecute(ProfileModificationOperation.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningOperation.execute(ProvisioningOperation.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.ProvisioningOperationRunner$1.run(ProvisioningOperationRunner.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2009-10-05 21:25:28.201
!MESSAGE An error occurred while uninstalling
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2009-10-05 21:25:28.202
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.ant.ui 3.4.0.v20090520 --> [R]org.eclipse.ant.ui 3.4.1.v20090901_r351, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2009-10-05 21:25:28.202
!MESSAGE Error while loading manipulator.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while loading manipulator.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.loadDelegate(LazyManipulator.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.getConfigData(LazyManipulator.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction.uninstallBundle(UninstallBundleAction.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.UninstallBundleAction.execute(UninstallBundleAction.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ParameterizedProvisioningAction.execute(ParameterizedProvisioningAction.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Phase.mainPerform(Phase.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningUtil.performProvisioningPlan(ProvisioningUtil.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProfileModificationOperation.doExecute(ProfileModificationOperation.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningOperation.execute(ProvisioningOperation.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.ProvisioningOperationRunner$1.run(ProvisioningOperationRunner.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be related to [**bug 285743**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=285743): as explained in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.equinox/msg06630.html)

> What happens is that P2 fails to correctly setup `osgi.install.area`, because it doesn't strip 'plugins' part from the path. I saw this happen when eclipse.ini file in target directory didn't have '`-startup`' option in it.
>
> Take a look into your eclipse.ini file if it contains `-startup` option like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20080819.jar
```

Note: if this is the case, you can refer to "proper" eclipse.ini to avoid any settings-related problem (for eclipse3.4 or 3.5.x): see **["good" eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)**.

Comment: I didn't have startup option at all in my eclipse.ini
But I added the option and it started working :)
Thanks..
Even the regular eclipse update works now!

Comment: Also, make sure it is a carriage return and not a space between the setting name and its value. Spaces can cause problems...